# Go To Meeting on Ubuntu: Possible, and if not, which alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation

### Problem

In my company, an Open Source BPM solution editor, we use a lot Go To Meeting and Go To Training (Citrix) for trainings. It works on Windows, Mac and iOS, Android. But not on Linux. And it seems they will not support Linux soon. I know that Webex (Cisco) supports Linux, but is far more expensive and the CTO told us "No!".

Thanks to the success of our Open Source solution, we have more and more demand for training with Ubuntu desktop & server, and we would like to be able to do it. Skype is not a solution, and Google Hangouts neither.

### Question

So, would you have any advice? We need:

- sharing screen & webcam
- managing who speak (mute, unmute)
- a text chat
- up to 6 people connected + manager of the session
- record the session
- the ability to do some remote control over the Internet would be a plus but is not compulsory

If it is Linux only, it is not a problem. If it is not free of charge, it must not cost much than Go To Training.

There is an interesting comparison chart on Wikipedia, however, there are too many to test them all. So if you have any feedback, you are welcome.

### Reference

- http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/training/online_training
- http://www.webex.com/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_conferencing_software

Comment: Why isn't Skype or Google hanghouts an option? they are quite good and are stable.

Comment: Looks like Psi/Psi+ Jabber/XMPP clients have some audio/video support by [using a plugin](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=620032). You'll then need to set up a Jabber/XMPP server yourself, though. It's defenitely not a conference solution. I doubt this even exists - I only know hosted solutions like Spreed.

Comment: You don't have enough control to manage a training (mute, unmute someone, for example). Some other cool features are the recording ability, I will add it to the list.

Comment: Be sure to let Citrix know you want GoToMeeting on [Linux](https://community.gotomeeting.com/gotomeeting/topics/develop_gotowebinar_for_all_32_bit_and_64_bit_linux_operating_systems)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I will vote for that !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenMeetings](http://openmeetings.apache.org/index.html)

> Openmeetings provides video conferencing, instant messaging, white board, collaborative document editing and other groupware tools using API functions of the Red5 Streaming Server for Remoting and Streaming.

[Mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com/product/what-is-mikogo/)

> Mikogo is a desktop sharing tool full of features to assist you in conducting the perfect online meeting or web conference.
>   Take advantage of the opportunity to share any screen content or application over the Internet in true color quality with up to 25 participants simultaneously, while still sitting at your desk.

[Yugma](https://www.yugma.com/)

> Yugma free web conferencing allows anyone, anywhere to instantly share their desktop and ideas online with others. To start hosting your own meetings, sign up today for FREE. Your Yugma Free web conferencing account allows you to invite up to 1 attendees with 30 minutes meeting limitations.

Comment: I think that Apache OpenMeetings is the best option because meets all the requirements from the OP and it's open source (then free). I didn't know about its existence and I'm going to implement one server now at home. Thanks for that great answer!

Comment: Yes, this a surprise for me too...

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend Teamviewer.  It's free and available on all devices. Or Google chrome remote connection for a bit more stability.

Comment: To complete your answer, could you please add a link to Teamviewer website?

Comment: this is not a training solution, this it an assistance solution

Answer (score 4):

Yes, now it's possible run GoToMeeting on Ubuntu: there is a new HTML5 version, which runs fine under Chrome (tested in 14.04 and 16.04). No need to use Phone for audio.

Open it at:

https://app.gotomeeting.com

Or if you want to directly open the meeting using the ID:

```
https://app.gotomeeting.com/index.html?meetingid=<id>
```

Then you can create a Web App in Chrome, clicking in the sandwich icon, then `More Tools` > `Create application shortcuts`.

**Update**: According @cr8ivecodesmith, the web client now supports hosting meetings/webminars!

Comment: We tested a few times, at the moment, this is not possible to host the webinar or meeting. Only to join and view/participate.

Comment: @ttoine Thanks for the update (I'll update my answer). As I just joined a meeting yet using it, I was not aware of it. At the support, GotoMeeting guys said this HTML5 version will be the future, so it'll be receiving all the features.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha: You're a lifesaver man! finally found the correct link :)

Comment: I'm the Community Leader for GoToMeeting as well as an Ubuntu user :) GoToMeeting has a Web App (WebRTC based client), that can be used to attend meetings from your web browser. In Chrome it supports GoToMeeting's VoIP and you can also be made presenter and share your screen or application window. Hosting meetings is being worked on still but one work around is to start the meeting using one of the mobile Apps and then making the Linux PC or ChromeBook the presenter. If you have any questions you can reach me on Twitter @GoToSupport or in our community community.gotomeeting.com

Comment: Thanks Glenn. An issue we have is that  the web client can not share a full screen at the moment. So it is difficult to use Powerpoint or LibreOffice. Also, a lot of our users have issues to join a session (some are customers who pay to join a training or live support), and records are not working well. You really need to improve your new version.

Comment: Is the site down? I can't seem to open it on chrome. It says site can not be reached.

Comment: @Sisir, yeap, the `.at` domain appears to be down. Use https://app.gotomeeting.com instead. I'll update the answer. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: For anyone reading this, the GoToMeeting web client now supports hosting/organizing meetings via Linux. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

[Big Blue Button](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/) is OOS educational software which covers your requirements (sans remote control). You can download a VM appliance with all set. Linux server and browser for a client.

The sad part is that it uses Flash, but nothing is ideal in this world.

Comment: You know if a company is offering hosting and services for Big Blue Button? Or we have to host it?

Comment: I have hosted it on VM at home (cable) for a small group (3-4 people) w/o a problem. On their web site they have some companiesh which provide hosting as well: http://www.bigbluebutton.org/commercial-support/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Facewebinar](https://www.facewebinar.com/) a free web based video audio conferencing tool.

Facewebinar is an amazing way to promote collaboration for globally diverse teams. It provides great quality and amazingly easy to use. It's helping me with my professional work as well as keeping in touch with family around the globe!